# Insert data into joined tables

Tags: mysql

I can select and join, but I can't insert with these below tables in the same time. How to insert data into joined tables?

- `company(cid, comp_name)`
- `role(rid, role_name)`
- `user(uid, user_name, cid, rid)`

`cid`,`rid` and `uid` are auto incremented primary keys.

I want to accept `user_name`,`comp_name`,`role_name` from the front end app and enter the user_name with corresponding `cid` and `rid` in user table. I am able to fetch the data after join from the user table but i don't know how to insert.

I have written a query:

```
INSERT INTO user ( user_name, cid, rid)
SELECT c.cid, r.rid FROM company c
    JOIN user u
    join role r ON c.cid = u.cid and r.rid=;
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert in three different tables at the same time. You have to make three different queries.

**Example:**

```
INSERT INTO user ( user_name, cid, rid) values (/*Variables for user_name, cid, rid*/)
INSERT INTO company( cid, comp_name) values (/*Variables for cid, comp_name. cid must have been same as cid above then store it in a variable and use it everywhere*/)
INSERT INTO role( rid, role_name) values (/*Variables for role*/)
```

If it is not what you want then please explain your questions clearly.

Or you can use Scop_Identity()
i-e 
"insert into tbl1 values
(@name, @age, @address)

insert into tbl2 values
(scope_identity(), @roleid)"